# Connect list view webpart present on modern page to SPFX webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, list-view, spfx

How can we connect listwebpart present on modern page to SPFX in SharePoint online?

On SharePoint modern page, i have list view of list X and a SPFX webpart. How can i pass data from list view to SPFX?. In on premise, connectable webpart property present but in online how can achieve same?

Comment: Hi Yogender, can you please clarify what you mean by "connect listwebpart present"? I don't think I understand.

Comment: On SharePoint modern page, i have list view of list X and a SPFX webpart. How can i pass data from list view to SPFX?. In on prim, connectable webpart property present but in online how can achieve same?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for Dynamic Data Connections in the SharePoint Framework.
You can connect two or more SharePoint Framework components together and exchange data between them using dynamic data.

Official document for your reference:
[Connect SharePoint Framework components using dynamic data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data)

Comment: Yes multiple SPFX can be connected by making them as source and consumer. But how connect SPFX with OOB list view as was possible in Sharepoint onpremise

Answer (score 0):

It appears that we can only connect:

- OOB webparts between each other. [See list here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec?ns=spostandard&version=16&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=spo160&helpid=spo_connectwebparts&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#bkmk_listproperties).
- Two or more custom SPFx webpart.

However, there is no way to subscribe a custom SPFx webpart to the OOTB webparts. At least it's not officially described anywhere. I have a suspicion that with some hacking it can still be done, but it's not documented yet.

[Quote from https://docs.microsoft.com:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/307847/how-can-we-connect-listwebpart-present-on-modern-p.html)

> For the OOB list, we cannot write custom code with it. You could use
> the OOB List properties web part to connect it.
>
> Refer to this documenatation for more:
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec?ns=spostandard&version=16&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=spo160&helpid=spo_connectwebparts&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#bkmk_listproperties